# Excel scrolling issues on second monitor

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, laptop, scrolling, dell-xps

We're encountering scrolling issues with Excel 2013 (and 2016).

What we mean by that is graphic distortions (blocks of black) appearing on the worksheet during the scroll action.

It happens almost exclusively on the externally attached monitor.

Even after the scrolling action is finished the blocks of blacks will persist and will obscure the data in the cells. Generally only opening the worksheet anew will correct the issue (until scrolling is once again initiated)

This is on a new Dell XPS 15 (9550) running Windows 10. The monitor is a Dell U2717D connected via the HDMI.

We've done quite a bit of troubleshooting but before describing in detail we wanted to know if anybody had seen something similar?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like rendering problem. Make sure that you have the latest graphics driver installed and that the computer has sufficient memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start any Office program.
2. On the `File` tab, click `Options`.
3. In the `Options` dialog box, click `Advanced`.
4. In the list of available options, click to select the `Disable hardware graphics acceleration` check box.

*For example, the following figure shows this option in Microsoft Excel.*

[image: The screenshot for the step 4]

5. Click OK.

Make sure you video drivers are up to date. You can try using the video drivers available from `Windows Update` if other drivers that you try still have this issue.

**Also see: How to determine whether your video configuration is compatible with Office**

Download the Office Configuration Analyzer Tool (OffCAT): [Microsoft Office Configuration Analyzer Tool 2.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36852)

References:

- [Display issues in Office client applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2768648)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same question as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1053006/excel-grey-and-black-boxes-on-secondary-display). A solution provided there works, unfortunately it's not been accepted and can't be commented upon.

Open `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\excel.exe.manifest` (location may vary, name stays the same). Go to line 23 and change

```
<dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
```

to

```
<dpiAware>false</dpiAware>
```

This should solve your problem.